# PHP Permissions Denied fopen

Tags: php, iis, file-io, fopen

I ran into a really bizarre problem. I am trying to perform writing to file using `fopen()`.

This is what I tried in `writetofile.php`:

```
$fw = fopen('/test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fw, 'hello world' . "\r\n");
fclose($fw);
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Warning: fopen(/test.txt): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\writetofile.php on line 41
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given...
```

I am 100% sure I have permissions to the server. I am the Administrator. Furthermore, I temporarily gave full permissions to everyone. I even tried running the php script locally, directly from the server using `localhost`. I am not using apache, I am using IIS. I tried restarting IIS after modifying permissions. I am not running php in safe mode.

Any idea on what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/test.txt` would be a file in the ROOT directory of your filesystem, where user accounts generally do NOT have write privileges (unless you're running this code as root). This is especially true of PHP running under the webserver's user account.

You probably want just `test.txt` (no leading slash)` which will try to put the file into the script's "current working directory" - usually the same directory the script itself is in.

Comment: +1, This worked! Thank you! Question: Shouldn't `/test.txt` write to the root directory, which is the same as the working directory (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\) in my case?

Comment: Because PHP is running at the file system level. It couldn't less what URL you hit to actually run the php code. It doesn't see urls. It just sees files on your server's drive. It's not bound by the server's document root

Comment: No fopen() uses system paths and / is the root directory of your file system "./test.txt" would write a file in your current working directory

Comment: What would be an example of the root directory of my file system? Would it simply be `C:/` ? Would it be correct to say that trying to write to the `/` directory would be the same to trying to write to the root of `C:/` ?

Comment: on a windows system, yes. each drive has its own root, D:\, C:\, etc... on a unix system, there's only one root, `/`. PHP will politely translate unix-style paths to Windows ones for you, so generally you should only use unix-styles `/foo/bar/baz` type ones, not `c:\foo\bar\baz`. About the only time you'd want to use an absolute windows path is if you need to talk to a different drive. e.g script on c:\, but using a file on d:\

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now! Thank you! I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1- when you rollout website, delete all logs folder names

2- inside the code create folder name as below and create the logs insides

3- write at top of file.  (during init the web)

```
$ClientUserName   = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

function Data_Log($dataline)
{
 global  $ClientUserName;
 $dir = 'UserInputLog' ;
 $fileName = $ClientUserName. '_ServerWebLog.txt';

 if(is_dir($dir) === false)
  mkdir($dir);

  $fileName = $dir. '\\'.$fileName;

  $myfile = fopen($fileName, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite($myfile, "$dataline\r\n");
  fclose($myfile);

}
```